# Where is ActionBar Up Indicator Located

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-resources

I am using the Dark `ActionBar` Theme and the default Up Indicator is white, but with a gray tone.  I'd like to find the resource and make it something that is closer to #FFFFFF so it stands out a bit more;

I don't want to redesign it, just change the color.

I know I can change it to a custom image by adding to `styles`:

`<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_up_indicator</item>`

But Id' rather alter the real one rather than create one from stratch.  However, I can not find where this resource is.  I am not sure if it's a `png` or an `xml` file, or what.  Can someone guide me to the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find  them in the [Framework/Base resources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res):

- [MDPI](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png)
- [HDPI](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png)
- [XHDPI](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png)
- [XXHDPI](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png)

[ic_ab_back_holo_dark.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark.xml)

Comment: That was it.  I thought they would never call it "back" so I was searching for "up" only.  Thanks!